App stops when navigating to / from a composable displaying camera on Android 11
I have a bottom navigation app in the beginning stages. It has 5 navigation items, one of which displays the camera. When navigating between tabs, eventually the app stops either when landing on the camera screen, or when leaving, and not necessarily at first try.
The app doesn't stop on Android 12 or higher - everything works smoothly there.
Relevant dependencies:
    dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7" 
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0"
    implementation platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.05.00")
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3"
}

Bottom Navigation Setup:
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
    NavigationBar {
        navigationItems.forEachIndexed { _, item ->
            val isSelected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == item.route } ==    true
            NavigationBarItem(selected = isSelected, onClick = {
                navController.navigate(item.route)
            }, icon = {
                ...
            }, label = {
                ...
            })
        }
    }

The Camera composable:

@Composable
fun QRCodeScanner(onQRCodeScanned: (String) -> Unit) {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    AndroidView(
        factory = { ctx ->
            val previewView = PreviewView(ctx)
            val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(ctx)

            cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
                val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)

                val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST).build()
                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
                    ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(ctx), QRCodeAnalyzer(onQRCodeScanned)
                )

                try {
                    cameraProviderFuture.get().apply {
                        unbindAll()
                        bindToLifecycle(
                            lifecycleOwner,
                            CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
                            preview,
                            imageAnalysis
                        )
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(ctx))

            previewView
        }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
}

I don't have a specific exception thrown.
Some relevant logs before the app is stopped:
W  Class androidx.compose.runtime.snapsho Common causes for lock verification is and incorrect proguard optimizations.
E  mCameraPreviewStatus false 
E  Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"

D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Use case androidx.camera.core.Preview-f180928d-b3af-48b8-a6e9-457e5f674321249328391 ACTIVE 
D  Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-f180928d-b3af-48b8-a6e9-457e5f674321, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-135cf0bb-1c6c-450c-8dee-d29ac2c2acc2169432874]
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Use case androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-135cf0bb-1c6c-450c-8dee-d29ac2c2acc2169432874 ACTIVE 
D  Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-f180928d-b3af-48b8-a6e9-457e5f674321, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-135cf0bb-1c6c-450c-8dee-d29ac2c2acc2169432874]
W  Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers 
D  Preview transformation info updated. TransformationInfo{cropRect=Rect(0, 0 - 1024, 768), rotationDegrees=90, targetRotation=-1} 
D  Transformation info set: TransformationInfo{cropRect=Rect(0, 0 - 1024, 768), rotationDegrees=90, targetRotation=-1} 1024x768 false 
D  getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=90, isOppositeFacing=true, result=90 
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} CameraDevice.onOpened() 
E  updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame. 
D  Wait for new Surface creation. 
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENING --> OPENED 
D  Recalculating open cameras: 
    Camera                                       State
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@8e76ae0[id=1]                         UNKNOWN
    Camera@46b0b74[id=0]                         OPEN
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1) 
D  New public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null} from OPEN and null 
D  Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null} 
D  All use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-f180928d-b3af-48b8-a6e9-457e5f674321, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-135cf0bb-1c6c-450c-8dee-d29ac2c2acc2169432874] for camera: 0 
D  Surface created. 
D  Surface changed. Size: 1024x768 
D  Surface set on Preview. 
D  Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-f180928d-b3af-48b8-a6e9-457e5f674321, androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis-135cf0bb-1c6c-450c-8dee-d29ac2c2acc2169432874]
D  [androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl@b9a2329] getSurface...done 
D  Opening capture session. 
E  updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame. 
W  Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers 
D  New surface in use[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=1](androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@ebcef25} 
D  use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@ebcef25 
D  New surface in use[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=2](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@5ad2438} 
D  use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@5ad2438

E  Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"

E  Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname" 
D  Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct 
D  Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nb
D  Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct 
D  Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nb 
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Use cases [androidx.camera.core.Preview-f180928d-b3af-48b8-a6e9-457e5
D  All use case: [] for camera: 0 
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Resetting Capture Session 
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Releasing session in state OPENED 
D  Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 0 
D  Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 0 
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Closing camera. 
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENED --> CLOSING 
D  Recalculating open cameras: 
    Camera                                       State
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@8e76ae0[id=1]                         UNKNOWN
    Camera@46b0b74[id=0]                         CLOSING
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1) 
D  New public camera state CameraState{type=CLOSING, error=null} from CLOSING and null 
D  Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=CLOSING, error=null} 
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Resetting Capture Session 
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Releasing session in state CLOSING 
D  onSessionFinished() 
A  sp<> assignment detected data race 
E  Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" 
E  Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" 
D  Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 0 
W  type=1400 audit(0.0:2057493): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_persist_camer
D  use count-1, useCount=0 closed=false androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@ebcef25 
D  Surface no longer in use[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=1](androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequ 
D  use count-1, useCount=0 closed=false androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@5ad2438 
D  Surface no longer in use[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=0](androidx.camera.core.impl.Immedi 
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} CameraDevice.onClosed() 
W  type=1400 audit(0.0:2057494): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_persist_camer
D  {Camera@46b0b74[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: CLOSING --> INITIALIZED 
D  Recalculating open cameras: 
    Camera                                       State
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@8e76ae0[id=1]                         UNKNOWN
    Camera@46b0b74[id=0]                         CLOSED
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 0 (Max allowed: 1) 
D  New public camera state CameraState{type=CLOSED, error=null} from CLOSED and null 
D  Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=CLOSED, error=null} 
A  runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting... 
runtime.cc:655] Dumping all threads without mutator lock held 
runtime.cc:655] All threads: 
runtime.cc:655] DALVIK THREADS (33): 
runtime.cc:655] "hwuiTask1" prio=6 tid=28 Runnable 
runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13400020 self=0xb4000071bd75d0f0 
runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=25625 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x6fd6acbcc0 
runtime.cc:655]   | state=R schedstat=( 11185779 6118439 31 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=5 HZ=100 
runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0x6fd69d4000-0x6fd69d6000 stackSize=995KB 
runtime.cc:655

Notes:

I haven't added the code for the permissions since I believe I'm handling them correctly, and since the crash only happens occasionally and the camera sometimes works fine for a while, I dismissed that possibility
I am making some analysis on the image, but after removing all of that logic, the issue persists
I have one activity only and working fully in compose
I used squareupp's app to check for memory leaks, none found.

I have read about some old known issues with camerax, but this still seems like something I am not doing correctly, but I'm not sure where I should look for the solution.
Edit
It seems to be an issue with my navigation system. After simplifying the navigation to a simple two tab bottom navigation without navcontroller, the camera works fine. However that won't do in the long term...

D  Opening capture session. 

E  updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame. 

W  Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers 

Based on this log, I wonder if you are always closing the ImageProxy properly inside the ImageAnalysis analyzer i.e. QRCodeAnalyzer. The implementation of that part isn't in the provided code. Maybe add more logs there to ensure that each ImageProxy CameraX provides to the analyzer is always getting closed at the end of analysis.

I have completely removed the analyses code to test if anything changes and the result is the same.

On which thread you are processing image in QRCodeAnalyzer? Do it on background thread. Trigger callback on main thread after getting result from QRCodeAnalyzer.
